# finding the average of values in an array

Tags: c++

I am using a `for loop` to grab the values in a txt file.

I want to average the numbers together. So I am doing this,

```
int size = 0;
double sum = 0;


for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
{
    sum +=  data[i].getQuantity();
}
double avg = ((double)sum)/size; //or cast sum to double before division

std::cout << avg << '\n';

return 0;
```

When I cout avg I get `80nan`. I assume I need to do `atod` But I can't seem to implement this correctly.

What am I missing here to find the average of the values stored inside `getQuantity`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

struct Input
{
    friend std::istream& operator >>(std::istream& inp, Input& item);
    friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& outp, Input const& item);

    std::string group;
    float total_pay;
    unsigned int quantity;

    Input() : group(), total_pay(), quantity()
    {
    }

    Input(std::string groupIn, float total_payIn, unsigned int quantityIn) :
    group(std::move(groupIn)),
    total_pay(total_payIn),
    quantity(quantityIn)
    {
    }

    std::string const& getGroup() const { return group; }
    float getTotalPay() const { return total_pay; }
    unsigned int getQuantity() const { return quantity; }
};

std::istream& operator >>(std::istream& inp, Input& item)
{
    return (inp >> item.group >> item.total_pay >> item.quantity);
}

std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& outp, Input const& item)
{
    outp
    << item.getGroup() << ' '
    << item.getTotalPay() << ' '
    << item.getQuantity();
    return outp;
}


int main()
{
    std::ifstream infile("input.txt");
    if (!infile)
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to open input file" << '\n';
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    std::vector<Input> data;
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(infile, line))
    {
        std::istringstream iss(line);
        Input inp;
        if (iss >> inp) // calls our extaction operator >>
            data.push_back(inp);
        else
            std::cerr << "Invalid input line: " << line << '\n';
    }

    std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(),
              std::ostream_iterator<Input>(std::cout,"\n"));

    std::cout << data[2].getQuantity();


    int size = 0;
    double sum = 0;


    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        sum +=  data[i].getQuantity();
    }
    double avg = ((double)sum)/size; 

    std::cout << avg << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). `size` is `0` in the code you posted. That wouldn't work very well.

Comment: Where's the file reading and what's the definition of getQuantity ?

Comment: I added my code. ok Ill change the value of size and see if that works. But should it not add 1 to size each time it loops?

Comment: Yep, `size` is `0` so the loop doesn't loop and then you divide by 0.

Comment: Ok got it. I changed it to one then? Now my average is 8034 when it should be 56.67

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
int size = 0;
```

to

```
size_t size = data.size();
```

So you set correct value to the `size`, loop correct number of times and then divide by correct number instead of `0`.

Comment: its amazing to me that three people would take time out of their lives to down vote me. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You are dividing by `0` in this program, this will always result in an  `ERROR`
in a program because dividing by `0` is simply not possible.